# How do I downgrade octave package or install from source?

Tags: software-installation, downgrade, octave

I installed octave using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave
```

However, I need an older version of octave (older than 3.4.0) so I tried to first install all dependencies and installing octave 3.4.0 similar to instructions given in this link:

http://www.schoeps.org/home/2015/06/five-simple-instructions-to-compile-octave-4-on-ubuntu/

I get errors about dependencies like:

```
GLPK library not found
```

even though I already installed all GLPK libraries. If I proceed anyway and 'sudo make install', I get an error in the end 'Please type another input file name' with lots of warnings.

Is there any simpler way to downgrade a package by installing it by first method? I spent hours searching for a solution here, please help! Thanks!

Comment: what *version* of Ubuntu are you using? IIRC 12.04 has octave3.2

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04